# Arima model always predicts the same value in python implementation, R's Auto Arima however gives me a well function model. How to replicate?

Tags: r, time-series, python, arima

I have a series that looks like
[image: this]. (https://gyazo.com/8a460fed032c8989b93cf26d8820e431)
[image]

It shows very strong auto correlation ![AC]
(https://gyazo.com/4acd9b9bd32c70509bde1b8b874d6e33).
[image]
I have differenced it and then it looks like this. [image: differenced]. However, when I build the ARIMA model and predict values it always predicts the same.

[image]

```
n_predictions = 30
predictions = []
rolling_values = train.values

for n in range(n_predictions):
    arima_init = ARIMA(rolling_values, order=(2, 1, 4))
    model = arima_init.fit()
    prediction = model.forecast()
    np.append(rolling_values, prediction)
    predictions.append(prediction)
```

This is the summary of the model: [image: sum]

And an image of the predictions for the 30 days after the series ends. !(end)[https://gyazo.com/f714ac90de2fd277f226d9b1083e2f3d]

However, when I do the same in R with the auto arima following the answer from another post here. I get the following:

!(resultsR)[https://gyazo.com/c0a97992c1876048e0bd08e155ca50f6]

The code to generate this model is:

```
fit <- auto.arima(ts(series_ca, frequency=365), D=1)
```

How can I replicate the same with the python ARIMA model? And most importantly, what changes am I making to the model in R to perform so much better and not just predicting the same for every iteration.

Sorry for maybe little but stupid question but really scratching my head over this! I appreciate any answers and am really eager to learn! Cheers :)

Comment: You have included a lot of information in your question, however, it is often helpful to create a minimal reproducible example with a small dataset.  It can both help you self diagnose the problem and it can allow reviewers to quickly reproduce what you are seeing.